# Need two different textbox's to only allow numbers 0-9 and 1 decimal place

Tags: c#, visual-studio

OK all my of code is working to this point. But I am unable to enter a decimal place in textbox1 and textbox3. I also only want the numbers 0-9 to be able to be entered in those textbox's. So far everything to this point is working for me but when I enter a "." I get a error. I think once I get the decimal to be able to be entered I am sure I can add the negitive sign as well. I think I need to use e.KeyChar correct?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TemperatureConversion
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A program that turns Fahrenheit to Celsius.
    /// </summary>

    public partial class TemperatureConversionGYG : Form
    {
        // Varable for the calculatedCelsius output in textbox2
        float calculatedCelsius;

        // Varable for the Fahrenheit entered in textbox1.
        float originalFahrenheit;

        // Varable for the Celsius entered in textbox3.
        float originalCelsius;

        // Varable for the calculated fharenheit when user enters celsius to turn into fharenheit.
        float calculatedTemperatureFahrenheit;

        public TemperatureConversionGYG()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // When this button is clicked it will use the number the user inputs in textbox1(FahrenheitNumber) to 
            // calculate the degree celsius and output it in textbox2. 
            calculatedCelsius = (originalFahrenheit - 32) / 9 * 5; 

            //Code here to send the calculatedCelsius to textbox2
            textBox2.Text = calculatedCelsius.ToString();
        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // originalFahrenheit that the program will read and convert it to a float when user inputs a number.
            originalFahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        }

        public void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Need this box to accept 1 decimal. example 7.2, 55.5, 99 
        }

        private void Twitter_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Navigate to a URL.
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://twitter.com/GYGamers");
        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // originalCelsius that the program will read and convert it to a float when user inputs a number.
            originalCelsius = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This turns origianlCelsius to Fahrenheit.
            calculatedTemperatureFahrenheit = (originalCelsius * 9) / 5 + 32;

            //Code here to send the calculatedTemperatureFahrenheit to textbox4
            textBox4.Text = calculatedTemperatureFahrenheit.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Need this box to  accept  1 decimal. example 7.2, 55.5, 99 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: rather than fight with the user over what they can do on their machine you could convert their input or use a NumericUpDown; you already will have a problem if they enter "I like pie"

Comment: You can test the textbox if it ends with "." last char entered, Than append "0". That might solve the error.

Comment: @plutonix your are correct I get a error if I enter something like that.

Comment: you need to validate almost all input which originates from a text control. for what you are doing, a NumericUpDown would restrict aht they can enter to numberics and you could limit the decimals as well

Comment: [how to create a numerical textbox msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms229644(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate your inputs using Regex expression

**Sample code**

```
private bool IsValidValue(string text)
        {
            bool isValid;
            if (text.EndsWith("."))
            {
                text += "0";
            }
            if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^(\+|\-?)(((\d+)(.?)(\d+))|(\d+))$"))
            {
                isValid = true;
            }
            return isValid;

        }
```